# #1054 - Неизвестный столбец 'password_last_changed' в 'mysql.user'

Tags: сервер, denwer

После переустановки винды, устанавливал денвер, так как у меня на диске D уже была диреатория с денвером и соотвественно проектами в папке home и базами данных - я установил его у ту же самую папку.

все проекты и базы данных сохранились и работают, однако при создании нового пользователя мне пишет

```
#1054 - Неизвестный столбец 'password_last_changed' в 'mysql.user'
```

в интернете советуют

```
  Если это так, вам нужно запустить ' mysql_upgrade' script, чтобы перенести некоторые таблицы из старой версии в новую.

 run

 mysql_upgrade -u root -p

 и введите пароль root.

 тогда вы должны решить свою проблему.
```

но не в одной статье не говориться где я должен конкретно это прописать, у меня windows 10 естественно если я просто открою командную строку и начну в ней прописывать такое то мне выдаст что это не является внутренней командой

или может можно как то ге то в самом денвере поправить что бы он запускал mysql версии 5.5 - он у меня есть! и 5.7я версия мне на самом деле не нужна по факту